# How can I edit and plot live on PowerBI data streamed from a blob storage on Azure?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-iot-hub, powerbi-datasource

My setting is the following:

1. Data is obtained by device reading from a sensor.
2. Data is sent to IoTHub using C SDK
3. Data is stored in a blob storage container. The body of the message is encoded in base64.
4. The data is sent through a streaming job to PowerBI.
5. On PowerBI I would like to manipulate the data, to plot it live as it is streamed. However, this is not possible since the dataset cannot be manipulated unless it is downloaded (see [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Edit-Dataset/td-p/555879))

This is an example of the data stored in the blob:

```
{"EnqueuedTimeUtc":"2019-05-27T09:50:24.1430000Z","Properties":{},"SystemProperties":{"connectionDeviceId":"fbeac20************************36f7b1","connectionAuthMethod":"{\"scope\":\"device\",\"type\":\"x509Certificate\",\"issuer\":\"external\",\"acceptingIpFilterRule\":null}","connectionDeviceGenerationId":"63*************05722","enqueuedTime":"2019-05-27T09:50:24.1430000Z"},"Body":"SGVsbG8gZnJvbSBBenVyZSBJb1Qgc2FtcGxlIQ=="}
```

The "body" section contains the string "Hello from Azure IoT sample!" encoded in base64. Basically, I'd like to replace the example string with a JSON formatted string and decoded it from base64 to get its content, then convert the numbers from string to floats. But apparently this cannot be done "live". Is there a way around this?

Comment: What service or technical solution are you using for 4 - streaming job?

Comment: @PeterBons Azure Stream Analytics (I think is the complete name). It is the one available in Azure by searching "Stream Analytics".

Comment: Since you can write a [javascript function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions) in azure stream analytics you might be able to decode de base64 string in such a function.